# Same function with different action depending on caller

Tags: c#

I'm not sure if what I'm asking about is possible, so bear with me.

Currently I have multiple functions, each with the same loop bit and different action.

I would like a function who's main purpose is to loop through certain entries in a list and have different action based on the caller.

One solution I though of is to have a switch/if block and a unique variable from the caller to determine the action. However, I was more thinking along the lines of calling the function and some how passing in the action it should take on each entry.

Comment: It sounds like it would be easiest to just have two methods. Why do you need to combine two different behaviors in one method?

Comment: Based on the caller of which function? Could you be more specific and provide some a tiny example

Comment: A sidenote on terminology: There are no "functions" in C#. They're called "methods".

Comment: @Phil The looping bit is the longer and more complex bit compared to the action. Instead of having LoopForGreen(), LoopForRed(), LoopForBlue, etc. I'm looking for LoopFor(Blue).

Comment: what is "loop bit", basically loop?

Comment: @sllev: The `Func` delegate types were introduced with LINQ, which has very strong roots in functional programming. As such, the name makes sense: A `Func` delegate does, in a way, represent the idea of a function. But a delegate is not a function. A *delegate* delegates, so-to-speak, program execution to one or more *methods* when invoked. The term "function" in the context of the C# language is simply misplaced: C# has methods. In C#, you cannot declare a function outside of a type. The only edge case I can think of are anonymous methods (but even these get compiled into a class method).

Comment: @stakx: absolutely agree with you, I was not so literally when mean Func as function, but from such perspectives this is right

Comment: @Andrew I see now. Funcs and Actions are what you need then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps your function could take an [`Action<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) as a parameter, and each caller can provide its own action as an argument?

```
public void LoopOperation(Action<MyType> action)
{
    foreach(MyType myObject in myCollection)
    {
         action(myObject);
    }
}
```

You could call it like the following:

```
LoopOperation(o => Console.WriteLine(o.ToString()));
```

Or perhaps like the following:

```
LoopOperation(o => o.SaveToDatabase());
```

Or with any other operation you want to perform.

Answer (score 4):

You could use some form of a lamba (predicate) where you could do something like

```
public void dosomethingfunciton(Func<YourType, ResultType> func)
{
     foreach(vat item in List)
     {
        var result = func(item);
     }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could simply add a parameter to the function that would be used to determine which action has to be taken.

```cs
public enum CallerType {
    RedCaller, GreenCaller, BlueCaller
}

public MyResultType MyFunction(CallerType callerType)
{
    switch (callerType) {
        case CallerType.RedCaller:
            DoRedCallerStuff();
            break;
        case CallerType.GreenCaller:
            DoGreenCallerStuff();
            break;
        case CallerType.BlueCaller:
            DoBlueCallerStuff();
            break;
        default:
            DoDefaultStuff();
            break;
    }
}
```

---

The parameter could also the caller itself. Assuming that the classes `RedCaller`, `GreenCaller` and `BlueCaller` are all deriving from `CallerBase`. I am using [Declaration (C# 7.0) and type patterns (C# 9)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#declaration-and-type-patterns):

```cs
public MyResultType MyFunction(CallerBase caller)
{
    switch (caller) {
        case RedCaller:
            DoRedCallerStuff();
            break;
        case GreenCaller:
            DoGreenCallerStuff();
            break;
        case BlueCaller:
            DoBlueCallerStuff();
            break;
        default:
            DoDefaultStuff();
            break;
    }
}
```

or, if you need the strongly typed callers:

```cs
public MyResultType MyFunction(CallerBase caller)
{
    switch (caller) {
        case RedCaller redCaller:
            DoRedCallerStuff(redCaller);
            break;
        case GreenCaller greenCaller:
            DoGreenCallerStuff(greenCaller);
            break;
        case BlueCaller blueCaller:
            DoBlueCallerStuff(blueCaller);
            break;
        default:
            DoDefaultStuff(caller);
            break;
    }
}
```

In an object-oriented approach, you would let the callers themselves perform the action. The following call would perform the right action for all caller types automatically:

```cs
caller.TheAction();
```

`CallerBase` would declare the method `TheAction` either as `abstract` or as `virtual` and the deriving classes can then provide their own implementation.

Answer (score 2):

I thought about answering this question with the 'use a delegate' response that you seem to be reaching for... but then I thought to myself.. why? It's overly complex, especially if you're never going to reuse the 'action' code in some other routine.

So, I'm going to say something along the lines of KISS:

```
enum MyActions
{
   Action1,
   Action2,
   Action3
}

public DoStuff(MyActions theAction, Itemlist theList)
{
   foreach (SomeItem in theList)
   {
       // do any common stuff

       switch (theAction)
       {
           case Action1:
              //Action 1 specific stuff
              break;
           case Action2:
              //Action 2 specific stuff
              break;
           case Action3:
              //Action 3 specific stuff
              break;
       }
   }
}
```

I know... basic.... but simple, and does the job.

Comment: I don't know about you, but if a person understands what a delegate is and how to use one, I think the delegate approach is a little simpler, cleaner, and more flexible.

Comment: It just really seemed like this was a case where the code was being over-engineered. Unless the code (the action) is going to be reused by passing it into another type of function, what need is there to make it into a delegate/pass a generic/inherit, etc? We just need the code to branch based on actiontype.

Comment: You basically had the same idea. 1+

Comment: A switch statement would be good in some simple scenarios, I'll agree. But for many more complex scenarios a switch statement will complicate the method. And it can create a potentially very long method, which is a code smell. Then you have the fact that a switch statement is less flexible than passing a lambda as a parameter. The inversion of control that a lambda provides just seems better in design and is still simpler, unless your switch statement is really trivial.

Comment: Yep. Based on Andrew's further explanation in his comment on the original post, I suspect this is a simple situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an action to the function. Look at the delegates `Action`, `Action<T>`, and so on to see some examples on how to pass "actions" to a function.

Answer (score 1):

For a slightly alternative strategy, you could achieve this with interitance: eg

```
public abstract class BaseLooper<TItem>
{
    public void DoLoop (List<TItem> list)
    {
        foreach (TItem item in list)
        {
            DoLoopAction(item);
        }
    }

    protected abstract void DoLoopAction(TItem item);
}

public class BlueLooper
    : BaseLooper<BlueClass>
{
    protected overrides DoLoopAction (BlueClass item)
    {
        ...Do Stuff
    }
}
```

Note: I've not run this so there's probably the odd error, but I'm sure you get the idea!

The benefits of this are that the actions performed in the loop can be really messy - other calls, properties on the child class to be brought in etc etc.